# Using pip with 'insecure' mercurial

Tags: ssl, mercurial, pip, sni

Is it possible to use pip with a requirements file to install from a Mercurial repository which needs to be accessed using --insecure in order to work.

The repository is accessed via SSL, and due to pip ignoring Server Name Indication (SNI), a valid SSL certificate is not being honoured (it uses the main certificate for the IP address). --insecure gets round this issue

ie:

```
hg clone https://username@domain.org/username/app_name --insecure
```

So where you can usually do something like this:

```
pip install -e hg+https://username@domain.org/username/app_name#egg=app_name
```

or have the following in a pip requirements file:

```
hg+https://username@domain.org/username/app_name#egg=app_name
```

Neither of these work due to the SSL SNI issue.

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use [hostfingerprints] in your ~/.hgrc?

For example:

```
[hostfingerprints]
example.com = 38:76:52:7c:87:26:9a:8f:4a:f8:d3:de:08:45:3b:ea:d6:4b:ee:cc
```

To obtain the self-signed certificate, follow the steps suggested in https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates

> The root CA certificate for a server can for example be retrieved with
>   Firefox. Browse to https://example.com/repo and verify that this is the
>   repository you trust, click the lock symbol in the lower right corner,
>   View Certificate, Details, select the certificate at the top of the
>   Certificate Hierarchy, Export, "X.509 Certificate (PEM)" and save
>   somewhere for example as server.pem. With other browsers on Windows
>   you have to view the certificate at the top of the Certification Path
>   and "Copy to File" as "Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)". Several such
>   files can be concatenated into one cacerts file.

Comment: FWIW it's worth, this answer is relevant even if you're not using pip. I have a professionally signed certificate (Comodo), but recently relinquished the unique IP that the server was based on due to my ISP hiking up prices due to IPv4 address rarity. For that to work, the things accessing stuff hosted on the server need to support SNI, which Mercurial (2.7.1 at least) doesn't. Telling Mercurial that I really, positively do trust things on that domain gets me around the problem.